# Questions about SU(2) matrices

Tags: group-theory

The matrix representation $U$ for the group $SU(2)$ is given by

$$U = \begin{bmatrix}
       \alpha & -\beta^{*} \\
       \beta & \alpha^{*} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers and $|\alpha|^{2}+|\beta|^{2}=1$.

This can be derived using the unitary of $U$ and the fact that $\text{det}\ U=1$.

---

Is any complex $2\times 2$ matrix with unit determinant necessarily unitary?

---

Consider the following argument:

$$\text{det}\ (U) = 1$$
$$(\text{det}\ U)(\text{det}\ U) = 1$$
$$(\text{det}\ U^{\dagger})(\text{det}\ U) = 1$$
$$\text{det}\ (U^{\dagger}U) = 1$$
$$\text{det}\ (U^{\dagger}U) = \text{det}\ (U)$$
$$U^{\dagger}U = U$$
$$U^{\dagger}= 1$$

Where's my mistake in this argument?

Comment: Two matrices with the same determinant are not necessarily equal, which you've assumed 2 steps from the bottom.

Comment: Any help with my first question about the unitarity (or not) of a matrix with unit determinant?

Comment: Consider $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: What is the most general complex $2\times 2$ matrix with unit determinant that you can write down?

Comment: This is becoming a chameleon question (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in passing from $\text{det}\ (U^{\dagger}U) = \text{det}\ (U)$ to $U^{\dagger}U = U$. There is no reason for that:
$$
\text{det} A=\text{det} B\not\Rightarrow A=B\quad (!)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that the determinant is not inversible and 
$$det(U{}^TU) = det(U)$$
definitely doesn't imply
$$U{}^TU = U$$